# Toggle link with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this code :

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn">Link2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn">Link3</a>
<div>Content link 1</div>
<div>Content link 2</div>
<div>Content link 3</div>
```

I want that each link matches to its div (Link1 => Content link 1, Link2 => Content link 2, ect .....)

I wrote this Javascript

```
        $('div').hide();

             $(".btn").click(function () {
               $(this).next("div").slideToggle('slow');
           });
```

But it does not work. If someone could help me.

Comment: Coud i add id's to your HTML code for solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a link between each content div and the button to activate it. You also need to start all content divs as hidden.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(elm) {
  $('.content').hide();
  console.log($(this).attr('data-link'))
  var id = $(this).attr('data-link')
  $('#' + id).slideToggle('slow')
})
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-link="link1" href="#" class="btn">Link1</a>
<a data-link="link2" href="#" class="btn">Link2</a>
<a data-link="link3" href="#" class="btn">Link3</a>
<div id="link1" class="content">Content link 1</div>
<div id="link2" class="content">Content link 2</div>
<div id="link3" class="content">Content link 3</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('div').hide();

$(".btn").click(function () {
  var index = $(this).attr("data-index");
  $("div[data-index!='"+index+"']").slideUp('slow', function(){
    $("div[data-index='"+index+"']").delay(400).slideDown();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-index="1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-index="2">Link2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-index="3">Link3</a>
<div data-index="1">Content link 1</div>
<div data-index="2">Content link 2</div>
<div data-index="3">Content link 3</div>
```

Comment: It works ! But when you click on a link I want the others to close

Comment: Now it closes and animates the other divs

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the .next selector. You will always end up selecting the first div.

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-rel="div1">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-rel="div2">Link2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-rel="div3">Link3</a>
<div id="div1">Content link 1</div>
<div id="div2">Content link 2</div>
<div id="div3">Content link 3</div>

  $(".btn").click(function (evt) {
   var rel = $(this).attr('data-rel');
   $("#"+rel).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your provided markup:

```
$('div').hide();
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $('div').hide(); // hide open divs
    var index = $(this).siblings().andSelf().index(this);
    $(this).nextAll("div").eq(index).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways doing so, but i find this more easy and handy. I have used :eq(index) of JQuery.

> Just as in CSS we have tag:nth-child(num); in JQuery there is this
>   :eq(index) to select specific tag that are siblings.

For Example:

**HTML**

```
<li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li> <li>4</li>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("li:eq(2)").hide();
```

> Now what it does it selects the **third** li tag and hide. Yes it's
>   index starts from 0(Zero)

Your Solution

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p71s0kg8/)

**HTML** just added id to your anchor tags

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="1">Link1</a>

<a href="#" class="btn" id="2">Link2</a>

<a href="#" class="btn" id="3">Link3</a>

<div>Content link 1</div>
<div>Content link 2</div>
<div>Content link 3</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("div").hide(); /* At beginning hiding all div's */ 
$("a").click(function(){
    var curId = this.id; /* Find and store id of <a> tag is clicked */
    var findId = curId-1;/* This is for :eq() selector */
    $("div").slideUp();/*Hide the rest div if visible accept the one clicked */
    $("div:eq("+ findId +")").fadeToggle();
});
```